# How to set up auto reloading function on slideshow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have slideshow which i want to start with start() and stop with stop(). but it doesn't work. I have defined everything, included stop and start functions. Below i typed my html and javascript codes. When i click on Start button, it doesn't go automatically, i must click each time to get it in process

```
    <DOCTPYPE! >
<html>
<head>
<style>
#imgs img {
float: center;
 box-shadow: 5px;
}
input {

float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}
input:last-child {

margin-left:5px;
}
</style>
<script src="ghgh.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div >
   <img src="1.jpg" id="myPhoto" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" />

</div>
<input type="button" value="start" onClick="start();" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onClick="stop();" />

<body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myPhoto");
var imageArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;

function start () {

myPhoto.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
imageIndex++;
if(imageIndex  >= imageArray.length) {
 imageIndex = 0;

}

}


var intervalHandle = setInterval (start (), 2000);

function stop() {

clearInterval(intervalHandle);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: Start button doesn't work. when i click on it, slideshow doesn't go automaticaly

Comment: first, when calling a function, try not to leave spaces start(). The same for the index of your array imageArray[imageIndex].  Finally, you can make a jsfiddle of this...

Comment: One issue is the call to setInterval.  It's executing the start function on the line where the setInterval is called, not on the interval itself.  Not sure if that would give an error to break the code, but possibly.  Does changing it as follows fix it?

var intervalHandle = setInterval(start, 2000);

Comment: Alternately, that could be "setInterval(function(){start();}, 2000);"

Comment: Heres a Fiddle for people trying to help you out: https://jsfiddle.net/uhmLvznw/3/

Comment: just replace start instead of start() ---- > `var intervalHandle = setInterval (start, 2000);`

Comment: @Giorgi you should reply to this comments. So we can know that , this works for you or not. I have given answer. check it . If it does not works for you than comment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```js
var myImage = document.getElementById("myPhoto");
var imageArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var is_stop = 0;
var time = 0;

function start () {
is_stop =0;
myPhoto.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
imageIndex++;
if(imageIndex  >= imageArray.length) {
 imageIndex = 0;

}
  if(!is_stop){
    time = setTimeout(start, 2000);
  }

}


function stop() {

  is_stop = 1;
  if(time){
    clearTimeout(time);
    }

}
```